# How to tell if a html string will show as empty in the browser? (C# / regex?)

Tags: c#, html, regex, string

I have a control that will return some html to me as a string. Before putting that on screen, I'd like to be able to tell if it'll just show as empty.

For example the control might return `<p><br /></p>`, which when I test using C# for string.Emtpy obviously it's not - but nothing gets displayed on screen.

Is there a regex function to test whether html will actually show any text on screen? Or using C# - is there any function to test the string containing html to see whether it actually contains anything other than tags?

Cheers, I'm a little confused how to get around this without writing some custom parser, a road I don't want to have to go down!

Comment: I would imagine that it would be the responsibility of the control to check the string to be included and then not to render anything if the string was semantically null.

Comment: Please not regex. Use a HTML parser that can get a the contents of a tag (without children tags but with their content).

Comment: Lazarus - this is a 3rd party control, I've no way to modify the html it returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As answered by @Ignacio you should use something like the HTML Agility pack. Here's a sample bit of code that seems to work for your situation.

```
HtmlDocument docEmpty = new HtmlDocument();
docEmpty.LoadHtml("<p><br /></p>");

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<p>I am not empty...<br /></p>");

bool shouldBeEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(docEmpty.DocumentNode.InnerText);
bool shouldNotByEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);
```

Note: This sample uses the http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex parser.

Comment: I haven't used this parser - how would it cope with something like `<b>&nbsp;</b>` in this context?

Comment: Since I'm using the InnerText property in the code example it would return &nbsp; in the case you've listed.

Comment: Hey Kane, I've just been debugging an issue with this - if there is whitespace between <p> tags the InnerText will return the whitespace - so the test for IsNullOrEmpty returns false. A .Trim() is needed on the InnerText property.

Comment: So, how did you handle the &nbsp case?

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by others, you can use a HTML parser, which is a solid way to handle your need. But I think it would add much overhead, since the parser has to do a lot of stuff to understand the HTML code.

Maybe your idea to use regex is not so bad. It should be quicker too.
I suggest you use **Regex** to replace every opening and closing tag with empty string. Everything that is not replaced should be some text to appear in the internet browser ...

```
string input = "<p> <br />  </p>";
  string pattern = "<[^<>^]+?>";
  string replacement = "";
  string result1 = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,replacement);
  pattern = "[\s\t\n]*"; ///filter for space, new line, tab 
  string result_final = Regex.Replace(result1 , pattern, replacement);
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result_final)) ... /// empty html
```

Comment: Your suggestion requires the property that eliminating a tag does not eliminate something displayed. Suppose the text is "<HR>". If you eliminate that then you go from HTML which displays something to HTML which displays nothing.

Comment: true, but Neal's question was :"Is there a regex function to test whether html will actually show any text on screen?"
<HR> does not display "text".
I think my solution is still good when you don't want to use a too complex (external) parser as an HTML parser.
Then remark that, Parser or Not, how do you handle the case of displaying (transparent) images ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with @kane's answer is that there are times where the innertext is legitimately empty...such as

```html
<p><a href="http://somewhere.com"><img src="image/page" /></a></p>
```

If you simply rely on `innertext`, then that guy up top would be flagged as empty.

I love the HTML Agility Pack, but be sure to check the innerhtml as well...

Comment: That's a good heads up; You could improve upon Kane's idea to not consider self-closing tags as <img/>, <br/>, and so on.
I don't see a too general solution because someone may need to consider <hr/> as relevant, others may not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write a custom parser, just use [an existing parser](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) and apply some search rules to it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's relevant but I made this test, and it seems to be what the OP wants, without using any external library (but requiring .Net > 3.0)

```
XElement docEmpty = XElement.Parse("<p><br /></p>");
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(docEmpty.Value)); // Outputs True.

XElement doc = XElement.Parse("<p>This is a test<br /></p>");
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc.Value)); // Outputs False.
```

Comment: Hi Shimrod, this doesn't work so well when the HTML isn't well formed, or isn't in fact HTML. For example, sometimes the control will return the string surrounded by p tags, other times it'll just be the string itself. The HTML Agility Pack seems to handle this better.